# How long do apache access log files last?

Tags: apache, access-log

How long does the server keep access log files?

Today I accessed my server log files and noticed they only go back to August 19th. Are access log files automatically dumped after a month?

If so, is there any way to recover them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how [log rotation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#rotation) is configured. In unix environments this task usually delegated to the logrotate daemon.

Comment: whats the default ? if any